# What is the difference when passing function's reference and lambda expression as arguments?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I am using custom comparators to `priority_queue`, finding different behaviors. I already knew that stl containers need specific type passing to template declaration.
When using normal functions, it should be:

```
bool cmp(pair<int, int> &lhs, pair<int, int> &rhs) {
    return lhs.first > rhs.first;
}
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(&cmp)> pq1(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);
```

But when using lambda, I find the correct way is:

```
auto comp = [](const pair<int, int>& lhs, const pair<int, int>& rhs){return lhs.second < rhs.second;};
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(comp)> pq2(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
```

I referred to [decltype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537655.aspx) but did not come out an opinion. Could someone explain how compiler treats `decltype(&function)` and `decltype(lambda)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) create an *object* (of an anonymous class).

If you use `&comp` then you get a pointer to the object, which is not callable.

---

The lambda you have is basically equivalent to

```
struct
{
    bool operator()(const pair<int, int>& lhs, const pair<int, int>& rhs)
    {
        return lhs.second < rhs.second;
    }
} comp;
```